# Need help with the following problem on the decoding of BCH codes?

Tags: coding-theory

I have to write down a quasi parity check matrix of a BCH code of lenth 63 over $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=\{0, 1, a, b=1+a\}$, then decode the vector $$a11abb10babbb01b1baaabba11bbaabaaaa001b0b1a1aa110110110b11b10bb \in \mathbb{F}_{2^2}^{63}.$$

I can decode vectors when the base field is $\mathbb{F_2}$, but I'm having difficulties doing the same here. We can't use computers for this(!), the problem is from a previous written exam.

Edit: it might be of use to know $p(x)=x^3 + x^2+ax+b$ is a primitive irreducible polynomial.

Comment: What's the designed minimum distance of the BCH code? Just asking so that I can help with the check matrix. BTW what's a *quasi parity check matrix*? I've been around, but I don't recall having seen such things :-) Anyway, I don't think I want to compute too many syndromes of a code of length 63 by hand :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Apologies for the late response. The designed distance is 3 (again, apologies for not mentioning this too before). And a quasi parity check matrix (maybe you're used to calling this by a different name) is supposed to be this: http://i.imgur.com/2xGoAWw.jpg

Comment: The code is narrow sense.